# os.IsNotExist but getting "not a directory"

Tags: go

I can not understand, why I am not able to create a folder and write to a file, and then read it in again - with the same path in same func, just for testing? 
When I run "go test myio_test.go" on the file. I get

myio_test.go

```
...
func TestMyIo(t *testing.T) {

    myio.CreateTempJsonFile()
}
....
```

myio.go

```
package myio

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "path"
    //"syscall"
    // "os"
    "bitbucket.org/kardianos/osext"
    "os"
)

func CreateTempJsonFile() {

    exePath, _ := osext.Executable()
    filePath := path.Dir(exePath + "/json/")
    fmt.Println("create: ", filePath)

    _, errx := os.Stat(filePath)
    if os.IsNotExist(errx) {
        errm := os.Mkdir(filePath, 0644)
        if errm != nil {
            fmt.Println("error creating dir...")
            panic(errm)
        }
    }

    writeError := ioutil.WriteFile(filePath+"/user.txt", []byte(`{"user": "Mac"}`), 0644) // os.ModeTemporary)// 0644)
    if writeError == nil {
        fmt.Println("Ok write")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Error write")
    }

    _, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filePath + "/user.txt")
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println("Reading file")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Error reading file")
    }
}
```

It is like the os.Stat(filePath) thinks the folder is already there. If I then remove the check for os.Stat() and just go and create the folder I get a panic "not a directory
"?

fmt.Println("create: ", filePath) prints:

```
/private/var/folders/yj/jcyhsxxj6ml3tdfkp9gd2wpr0000gq/T/go-build627785093/command-line-arguments/_test/myio.test/json
```

It is all strange, as each test creates a new "/go-buildxxx/" folder and therefore the folder should never actually be there?

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using [`ioutil.TempDir`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#TempDir) and `ioutil.TempFile` instead?

Comment: I think the error lies in bitbucket.org/kardianos/osext because it returns the path where the executable is at. When you are using Go run <program.go> a executable is made in a temp folder. If you use "go build" and then run your executable in the correct folder, it probably works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to split off the executable from it's base path as it's returned from `osext`

```
exePath, _ := osext.Executable()
base, _ := filepath.Split(exePath)
```

(or use `osext.ExecutableFolder()`)

Then you need to create the directory with the permissions `0755`. Directories need the executable bit set in order to traverse them.

Comment: nice I did not know about the executable bit

Comment: @fabrizioM, each bit has a slightly differnt meaning with respect to directories (including SUID, SGID, and the sticky bit): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Permissions